# How to make agile layout?

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have a few page on my web site that looks good only on wide-screen monitor. Something like this:

```
|========================|
|      H E A D E R       |
|========================|
|Block1 |     B I G      |
|-------|    D A T A     |
|Block2 |   B L O C K    |
|========================|
|      F O O T E R       |
|========================|
```

For people with small display it is not really friendly.

I see few options with how to address that.

**Option A**: Remove part of content or restructure it to have it normally displayed for narrow displays

```
|===============|
|  H E A D E R  |
|===============|
|Block1 | Block2|
|---------------|
|     B I G     |
|    D A T A    |
|   B L O C K   |
|===============|
|  F O O T E R  |
|===============|
```

**Option B**: Allow people to configure how they want to see these page(s): full-wide mode or narrow-screen mode. In first case page will be rendered as it is right now (1st table), and if people choose the 2nd approach it will be configured as described in the Option A (2nd table). This item require still to implement item #1, which is ok and acceptable

**Option C**: But the best approach seems to me to make UI agile: if page is wide then content div-elements are displayed in a row sequence; if page is narrow then they are displayed in a columns sequence.

So idea is that Block1, Block2 will have similar width and height and will be positioned by browser automatically.

**Question #1: how to implement Option C using HTML+CSS markup only?**

I do realize, that Block1, Block2 - should have style="float:left", but when I do block 2 is always on the right side from block 1 unless browser window is TOO narrow.
And "big block" is never on the right side from 2 small (see my code below)

**Question #2: Does it make sense trying to implement option C?**

P.S. Here is my prototype:

```
<html>
<head><title>Test blocks</title></head>
<body>

<style type="text/css">
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}
div.b1 {
    width:300px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
}
div.b2 {
    width:300px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}
div.big {
    width: 800px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
}
</style>
<div class="b1"> Block 1 </div>
<div class="b2"> Block 2</div>
<div class="big"> Big Data block</div> 

</body></html>
```

P.P.S. I put border to visible indicate those divs only, I won't have it in the final markup

Comment: That's called _responsive design_.  Look into media queries.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean under 'media queries'?

Comment: Google is your friend. Search those two phrases, individually

Comment: Thanks guys. Looks like what you recommended is to have few css configuration that explicitly declare positioning for particular browser window configurations? Something like having div.b1 style="float:left" if "@media (min-width: 900px)" and style="float:top" if "@media (min-width: 500px)". Am I on the correct way and should look more into this "@media" tag?

Comment: Many thanks to everybody. It looks like there is a new area to learn :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use a framework (my advice is to use it for save a lot of money, however use ZURB foundation that is mobile-first design) you have to learn what media query are:

```
@media (min-width:500px){
   CSS code that is readable only in device with more than 500px screen ;
}


@media (max-width:500px){
   CSS code that is readable only in device with less than 500px witdh screen;
}
```

And add this meta in to the  of your html code

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

To learn it and build something like you want, don't learn how to use the framework (bootstrap o Zurb foundation) but read the code of their "GRID system" and... take ispiration!

Comment: Happy to be helpfull :)

Answer (score 2):

Use something like Bootstrap. It has "this" meaning **responsive design** built into the framework.

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Hi Feitla, thanks for information. Do you really thing I need to learn the new framework to get aligned few divs? It is probably and most likely is not only about these 3 divs, but whole new framework, when I strongly believe pure CSS3 could work... ? Could you please comment on this?

Comment: It isn't just to "align a few divs". It is to align everything, including everything WITHIN the divs as well. The idea behind using a framework is consistency and following standards. If you want your site to be responsive... use the tools that are available. But to answer your question, there are other tools available besides bootstrap that can help you create a semi-responsive site. For example [1kbgrid.com](http://1kbgrid.com) or [1200px.com](http://1200px.com) or [responsivegridsystem.com](http://responsivegridsystem.com) etc. Use google.